# Reminder triggered when certain person calls?

Tags: iphone, ios, reminders

iPhone reminders have a nice feature where you can remind yourself to do something when arriving or leaving a certain location.

Is it possible to do something similar, but replacing the location trigger with a "person X calls trigger".  For example: "Reminder me to tell John that story when John calls."

In general, is there a way to attach additional triggers to reminders?

Comment: Nope, you can't. Android and Windows Phone only, sadly.

Comment: Is it impossible to do this with 3rd party apps as well?

Comment: Yes because iOS does not allow apps to see when someone is calling you. Your carrier could have a way to remind you about something when someone calls you, but that's a long shot.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way but when I need to do this, I change the contact name temporarily. Instead of "John" it would be "Tell John story".

Comment: Ha, pretty good hack

Comment: Easier if you change the nickname :)